# Copying array of pointers into device memory and back (CUDA)

Tags: arrays, pointers, cuda, cublas

I am trying to use `cublas` function `cublasSgemmBatched` in my toy example. In this example I first allocate 2D arrays: `h_AA, h_BB` of the size [`6`][`5`] and `h_CC` of the size [`6`][`1`]. After that I copied it to the device, performed `cublasSgemmBatched` and tried to copy array `d_CC` back to the host array `h_CC`. However, I got a error (`cudaErrorLaunchFailure`) with device to host copying and I am not sure that I copied arrays into the device correctly:

```
int main(){
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cudaError_t cudaerr;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cublasStatus_t stat;
    const float alpha = 1.0f;
    const float beta = 0.0f;
    float **h_AA, **h_BB, **h_CC;
    h_AA = new float*[6];
    h_BB = new float*[6];
    h_CC = new float*[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        h_AA[i] = new float[5];
        h_BB[i] = new float[5];
        h_CC[i] = new float[1];
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            h_AA[i][j] = j;
            h_BB[i][j] = j;
        }
        h_CC[i][0] = 1;
    }
    float **d_AA, **d_BB, **d_CC;
    cudaMalloc(&d_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*));
    cudaMalloc(&d_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*));
    cudaMalloc(&d_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*));
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_AA, h_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_BB, h_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_CC, h_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    stat = cublasSgemmBatched(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, 1, 5, &alpha,
             (const float**)d_AA, 1, (const float**)d_BB, 5, &beta, d_CC, 1, 6);
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(h_CC, d_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```

So this code works, however the last `cudaerr` returns `cudaErrorLaunchFailure`. I was trying to follow this sample code on [Github](https://github.com/pyrovski/cublasSgemmBatched-example/blob/master/gemm.cpp).

Thanks

P.S. What I don't understand, what is the `sizeof(float*)` and how `cudaMalloc` knows how many memory required for each array (like here I determine the size of 1 dimension only).

UPDATE: I did it!!:

```
cublasHandle_t handle;
cudaError_t cudaerr;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cublasStatus_t stat;
const float alpha = 1.0f;
const float beta = 0.0f;

float *h_A = new float[5];
float *h_B = new float[5];
float *h_C = new float[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    h_A[i] = i;
    h_B[i] = i;
}



float **h_AA, **h_BB, **h_CC;
h_AA = (float**)malloc(6* sizeof(float*));
h_BB = (float**)malloc(6 * sizeof(float*));
h_CC = (float**)malloc(6 * sizeof(float*));
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_AA[i], 5 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_BB[i], 5 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_CC[i], sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(h_AA[i], h_A, 5 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(h_BB[i], h_B, 5 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
float **d_AA, **d_BB, **d_CC;
cudaMalloc(&d_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaMalloc(&d_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaMalloc(&d_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_AA, h_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_BB, h_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_CC, h_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    stat = cublasSgemmBatched(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, 1, 5, &alpha, 
             (const float**)d_AA, 1, (const float**)d_BB, 5, &beta, d_CC, 1, 6);
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(h_CC, d_CC, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
        cudaMemcpy(h_C+i, h_CC[i], sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cublasDestroy(handle);
```

Comment: The messed up data you are passing is causing one of the kernels launched by the batch gemm call to fail.  As an asynchronous error, you may not receive notification of it until the next cuda call.  Have you studied the batched cublas [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#batchcublas) ?

Comment: I didn't, doing it right now

Comment: I did it!  Thanks. So, do I understand correct: In order to have a business with 2D device arrays, you should create host array of pointers  to device arrays, and after that copy this array to 2D device array memory. In order to retrieve 2D host array from 2D device array, you should again use intermediate 2D array, which is array of host pointers to device arrays. I posted working code into the Update

Comment: Yes, it is an example of a need for a deep-copy mechanism, which would be similar to what you would have to do if you wanted to copy a matrix to the device and be able to access it directly using double-subscript notation.  What you are calling 2D device arrays are still linear/flattened arrays.  The "2D" or deep-copy aspect of it comes in because you have an array of these arrays that you want to pass to the device, and this is analogous to the deep-copy mechanism required to pass a doubly-subscripted array.  Why don't you post your update as an answer.  It's OK to answer your own question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I figured out the answer (thanks to @Robert Crovella): in order to create `device array of pointers to device arrays` (for batched functions), one should first create `host array of pointers to device arrays`, and after that copy it into `device array of pointers to device arrays`. The same is true about transfering back to host: one should use intermediate `host array of pointers to device arrays`.

```
cublasHandle_t handle;
cudaError_t cudaerr;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cublasStatus_t stat;
const float alpha = 1.0f;
const float beta = 0.0f;

float *h_A = new float[5];
float *h_B = new float[5];
float *h_C = new float[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    h_A[i] = i;
    h_B[i] = i;
}



float **h_AA, **h_BB, **h_CC;
h_AA = (float**)malloc(6* sizeof(float*));
h_BB = (float**)malloc(6 * sizeof(float*));
h_CC = (float**)malloc(6 * sizeof(float*));
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_AA[i], 5 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_BB[i], 5 * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&h_CC[i], sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(h_AA[i], h_A, 5 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(h_BB[i], h_B, 5 * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
float **d_AA, **d_BB, **d_CC;
cudaMalloc(&d_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaMalloc(&d_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaMalloc(&d_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*));
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_AA, h_AA, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_BB, h_BB, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(d_CC, h_CC, 6 * sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
    stat = cublasSgemmBatched(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, 1, 5, &alpha, 
             (const float**)d_AA, 1, (const float**)d_BB, 5, &beta, d_CC, 1, 6);
    cudaerr = cudaMemcpy(h_CC, d_CC, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6;i++)
        cudaMemcpy(h_C+i, h_CC[i], sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cublasDestroy(handle);
```

Comment: I think it should be ```cudaMemcpy(h_CC, d_CC, 6*sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);``` just compare it with ```cudaMemcpy(d_CC, h_CC, 6*sizeof(float*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);``` it a typo?