# Pointer to Array of Pointers to Objects in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, cuda

I have followed the guidance offered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27931630/copying-array-of-pointers-into-device-memory-and-back-cuda) and [this link](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/387073/problems-with-creating-an-array-of-cuda-pointers/?offset=7) which deal with the concepts of passing arrays of pointers to a device and back but I seem to be struggling with my specific case when the pointer point to an object. See example code below where I have removed error checking for brevity.

```
// Kernel
__global__ void myKernel(Obj** d_array_of_objs)
{
    // Change the scalar of each object to 5
    // by dereferencing device array to get 
    // appropriate object pointer.
    *d_array_of_objs->changeToFive();    <--------- SEE QUESTION 4
}

// Entry point
int main()
{

    /********************************/
    /* INITIALISE OBJ ARRAY ON HOST */
    /********************************/

    // Array of 3 pointers to Objs
    Obj* h_obj[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        h_obj[i] = new Obj();       // Create
        h_obj[i]->scalar = i * 10;  // Initialise
    }

    // Write out
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << h_obj[i]->scalar << std::endl;
    }


    /**************************************************/
    /* CREATE DEVICE VERSIONS AND STORE IN HOST ARRAY */
    /**************************************************/

    // Create host pointer to array-like storage of device pointers
    Obj** h_d_obj = (Obj**)malloc(sizeof(Obj*) * 3);    <--------- SEE QUESTION 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Allocate space for an Obj and assign
        cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_obj[i], sizeof(Obj));
        // Copy the object to the device (only has single scalar field to keep it simple)
        cudaMemcpy(h_d_obj[i], &(h_obj[i]), sizeof(Obj), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    /**************************************************/
    /* CREATE DEVICE ARRAY TO PASS POINTERS TO KERNEL */
    /**************************************************/

    // Create a pointer which will point to device memory
    Obj** d_d_obj = nullptr;
    // Allocate space for 3 pointers on device at above location
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_d_obj, sizeof(Obj*) * 3);
    // Copy the pointers from the host memory to the device array
    cudaMemcpy(d_d_obj, h_d_obj, sizeof(Obj*) * 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    /**********
     * After the above, VS2013 shows the memory pointed to by d_d_obj 
     * to be NULL <------- SEE QUESTION 2.
     **********/


    // Launch Kernel
    myKernel <<<1, 3>>>(d_d_obj);

    // Synchronise and pass back to host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cudaMemcpy(&(h_obj[i]), h_d_obj[i], sizeof(Obj), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);     <--------- SEE QUESTION 3
    }

    // Write out
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << h_obj[i]->scalar << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So the questions are:

1. If the line indicated by `SEE QUESTION 1` above allocates host memory for the pointers, and once I have used `cudaMalloc` in the subsequent loop to allocate device memory, the pointer pointed to by h_d_obj get overwritten with device addresses, does that mean I have allocated host memory for 3 `Obj*` that now has no pointer pointing to it?
2. Why is the `cudaMemcpy` succeeding when I test the status returned but clearly does not copy the addresses correctly? I was expecting the "arrays" of memory address of both `h_d_obj` and `d_d_obj` to be the same since they should point to the same `Obj` in the device address space.
3. At the line `SEE QUESTION 3`, assuming I'm correct in question 2. I also expect to be able to use either `h_d_obj` or `d_d_obj` to retrieve the `Obj` objects from the device since the difference would be only whether I dereference a host pointer to access a device pointer to `Obj` or a device pointer both of which I can do in a `cudaMemcpy` method right? If I use what is written, the copy succeeds but the pointer at `h_obj[0]` is corrupted and I cannot write out the data.
4. At the line `SEE QUESTION 4`, why can I not dereference an `Obj**` to get a `Obj*` then use the `->` operator to call a **device** method? The compiler moans that it is not a pointer to class type which the fact that it is a `Obj*` tells me it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it's convenient if you provide a complete code, including a definition for the `Obj` class.  I've provided one based on inspection of your code and some guesswork.

Second, much of your confusion here seems to be a less-than-crisp facility with pointers in C (or C++).  Using the CUDA API with double-pointer constructions (`**`) between host and device requires a crisp understanding and ability to visualize what is happening.

> If the line indicated by SEE QUESTION 1 above allocates host memory for the pointers, and once I have used `cudaMalloc` in the subsequent loop to allocate device memory, the pointer pointed to by `h_d_obj` get overwritten with device addresses, does that mean I have allocated host memory for 3 Obj* that now has no pointer pointing to it?

No.  `h_d_obj` is established (i.e. given a meaningful value) by the `malloc` operation.  Nothing you have done subsequent to that modifies the value of `h_d_obj`.

> Why is the cudaMemcpy succeeding when I test the status returned but clearly does not copy the addresses correctly? I was expecting the "arrays" of memory address of both `h_d_obj` and `d_d_obj` to be the same since they should point to the same Obj in the device address space.

I don't see anything wrong with your code up to this point.  The value of `h_d_obj` was established (previously) by `malloc`, and the numerical value of it is an address in host memory.  The value of `d_d_obj` was established by `cudaMalloc`, and the numerical value of it is an address in device memory.  Numerically, I would expect them to be different.

> At the line SEE QUESTION 3, assuming I'm correct in question 2. I also expect to be able to use either `h_d_obj` or `d_d_obj` to retrieve the Obj objects from the device since the difference would be only whether I dereference a host pointer to access a device pointer to Obj or a device pointer both of which I can do in a cudaMemcpy method right? If I use what is written, the copy succeeds but the pointer at h_obj[0] is corrupted and I cannot write out the data.

NO.  You cannot dereference a device pointer in host code, *even* if it is a parameter in `cudaMemcpy`.  This is legal as a source or destination in a `cudaMemcpy` operation:

```
h_d_obj[i]
```

This is not legal:

```
d_d_obj[i]
```

The reason is that in order to get the actual target address, I must dereference a host pointer (i.e. access a memory location on the host) in the first case, but a device pointer in the second case.  From host code, I can retrieve the contents of `h_d_obj[i]`.  I am not allowed to try to retrieve the contents of `d_d_obj[i]` in host code  (and the parameter manipulation for `cudaMemcpy` is **host** code).  The value of `d_d_obj` can be used as a destination from host code.  `d_d_obj[i]` cannot.

> At the line SEE QUESTION 4, why can I not dereference an Obj** to get a Obj* then use the -> operator to call a device method? The compiler moans that it is not a pointer to class type which the fact that it is a Obj* tells me it is.

The compiler is barking at you because you don't understand the order of operations between the various operators (`*`, `->`) that you are using.  If you add parenthesis to identify the correct order:

```
(*d_array_of_objs)->changeToFive();
```

Then the compiler won't object to that (although I would do it slightly differently as below).

Here's a modified version of your code with the `Obj` definition addition, a slight change to the kernel so that independent threads work on independent objects, and a few other fixes.  Your code was mostly correct:

```
$ cat t1231.cu
#include <iostream>

class Obj{

  public:
  int scalar;
  __host__ __device__
  void changeToFive() {scalar = 5;}
};

// Kernel
__global__ void myKernel(Obj** d_array_of_objs)
{
    // Change the scalar of each object to 5
    // by dereferencing device array to get
    // appropriate object pointer.
    int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    // (*d_array_of_objs)->changeToFive();  //  <--------- SEE QUESTION 4 (add parenthesis)
    d_array_of_objs[idx]->changeToFive();
}

// Entry point
int main()
{

    /********************************/
    /* INITIALISE OBJ ARRAY ON HOST */
    /********************************/

    // Array of 3 pointers to Objs
    Obj* h_obj[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        h_obj[i] = new Obj();       // Create
        h_obj[i]->scalar = i * 10;  // Initialise
    }

    // Write out
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << h_obj[i]->scalar << std::endl;
    }


    /**************************************************/
    /* CREATE DEVICE VERSIONS AND STORE IN HOST ARRAY */
    /**************************************************/

    // Create host pointer to array-like storage of device pointers
    Obj** h_d_obj = (Obj**)malloc(sizeof(Obj*) * 3); //    <--------- SEE QUESTION 1
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Allocate space for an Obj and assign
        cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_obj[i], sizeof(Obj));
        // Copy the object to the device (only has single scalar field to keep it simple)
        cudaMemcpy(h_d_obj[i], &(h_obj[i]), sizeof(Obj), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    /**************************************************/
    /* CREATE DEVICE ARRAY TO PASS POINTERS TO KERNEL */
    /**************************************************/

    // Create a pointer which will point to device memory
    Obj** d_d_obj = NULL;
    // Allocate space for 3 pointers on device at above location
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_d_obj, sizeof(Obj*) * 3);
    // Copy the pointers from the host memory to the device array
    cudaMemcpy(d_d_obj, h_d_obj, sizeof(Obj*) * 3, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    /**********
     * After the above, VS2013 shows the memory pointed to by d_d_obj
     * to be NULL <------- SEE QUESTION 2.
     **********/


    // Launch Kernel
    myKernel <<<1, 3>>>(d_d_obj);

    // Synchronise and pass back to host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cudaMemcpy(h_obj[i], h_d_obj[i], sizeof(Obj), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  //   <--------- SEE QUESTION 3  remove parenthesis
    }

    // Write out
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << h_obj[i]->scalar << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1231 t1231.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1231
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0
10
20
5
5
5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

A diagram of `h_d_obj` and `d_d_obj` might help:

```
HOST                               |    DEVICE
h_d_obj-->(Obj *)-------------------------->Obj0<---(Obj *)<----|
          (Obj *)-------------------------->Obj1<---(Obj *)     |
          (Obj *)-------------------------->Obj2<---(Obj *)     |
                                   |                            |
d_d_obj---------------------------------------------------------|
HOST                               |    DEVICE
```

You're allowed to access any quantity (location) on the left hand side (HOST) of the above diagram, in host code, or in a `cudaMemcpy` operation.  You're not allowed to access any quantity (location) on the right hand side, in host code.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Crovella for your answer. The diagram is very helpful. Also thank you for being so polite in by describing my confusion as "less-than-crisp", very kind of you :)

Comment: I think I understand my mis-understanding in question 1. `Obj** h_d_obj = (Obj**)malloc(sizeof(Obj*) * 3);` allocates host memory enough to hold 3 pointers and returns a pointer to the memory to `h_d_obj` then `cudaMalloc((void**)&h_d_obj[i], sizeof(Obj));` dereferences `h_d_obj[i]` to get the i-th pointer in host memory (although this pointer has never been set), then gets the address of this pointer with `&` to which `cudaMalloc` returns the address of an `Obj` in device memory. So `h_d_obj` points to host memory with device pointers and although `h_d_obj` has changed `h_d_obj` hasn't.