# Memory allocation in cuda for a custom struct

Tags: struct, parallel-processing, cuda

I have these structs:

```
typedef struct Edge {
    int start;
    int end;
} Edge;

typedef struct {
    int deg;
    int nome;
    Edge *edges;
} Vertex;
```

and in my main function I have an initial structure `Vertex* initial_partition`, that contains all vertexes of a graph with all the field correctly filled.
Now I want to build a device structure that is exactly like this one, so I did:

```
Vertex* d_initial_partition;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex));
cudaMemcpy(d_initial_partition, initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

but I noticed that this operations doesn’t copy the field `Edge*` of the structure. I’ve tried even to allocate the edge alone like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; ++i) {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&d_initial_partition[i].edges, sizeof(Edge*));
    if(initial_partition[0].deg != 0){
            cudaMemcpy(d_initial_partition[i].edges, initial_partition[i].edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
}
```

or even like this:

```
Vertex* d_initial_partition;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex));
for(int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++){
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_initial_partition[i].edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge));
    cudaMemcpy(&d_initial_partition[i].edges, &initial_partition[i].edges, sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(&d_initial_partition[i], &initial_partition[i], sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

but nothing. Can someone let me see how can I save all the information in the `d_initial_partition` vector?

**UPDATE**
Following this answers below, I tried this code too

```
    Vertex* d_initial_partition;
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex));
cudaMemcpy(d_initial_partition, initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
    Edge* edges;
    // 2
    cudaMalloc((void **)&edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge));
    // copy edges
    if(initial_partition[0].deg != 0){
        cudaMemcpy(edges, initial_partition[i].edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
    
    cudaMemcpy(&d_initial_partition[i].edges, &edges, sizeof(Edge*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

But the code goes the same in segmentation fault if I try to access to one of the `edges` field `(end or start)`. In particular I noticed that the `edge` variable in the for loop, takes the values correctly, so the problem is on the `cudaMemcpy` of the`edge` into `d_initial_partition`

Comment: You are copying `initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge)` bytes, so you have to allocate (at least) `initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge)` bytes for the destination.

Comment: `initial_partition[i].edges` is a pointer to host memory. It is copied to the device, but that host memory can't be accessed from the device. There is no magic in `cudaMemcpy` - it just copies the actual bytes of memory. It doesn't/can't know/understand if some of these bytes are forming an address to host memory. If `edges` was a static array `Edge edges[NUM_EDGES];`, it would work, because the edges are part of the object. But because it is dynamic, it is just an address.

Comment: This kind of structure (also known as "Structure of Arrays"/SoA) is bad for performance, especially on the GPU due to the need for [coalescing of global memory accesses](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) if you want good performance in bandwith-bound algorithms. The ideal format will depend on what you are trying to do with your graph, but one classic way of storing a graph in HPC is using sparse matrix formats like CSR which flattens the edges into three arrays (offsets, values/weights and corresponding columns/"end"s).

Comment: If performance is not the priority, I would recommend using unified memory (`cudaMallocManaged()`) for these kinds of structures to avoid these kinds of headaches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy an object to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device)

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't resolve with that answer. How should I use `cudaMallocManaged`?
Should I do always as @MikeCAT showed below?

Comment: Unified memory is accessible from both host and device. So you can use it instead of `malloc` in the host code and just use it on the device without any segfaults. See [Unified Memory for CUDA Beginners](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/)

Comment: You can do the manual deep copy, but it is error prone, a lot of work and the arguably inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous questions here on the `cuda` tag that cover the topic of handling arrays of pointers and associated deep copies.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) is a question/answer that links to a number of them.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38978297/pointer-to-array-of-pointers-to-objects-in-cuda/38981438#38981438) is another, and there are many more.

To do a deep copy of nested structs, its necessary to allocate everything on the host, including device pointers, and then copy each item to the proper location.

Here is a worked example:

```cpp
# cat t149.cu
#include <cstdio>
const int num_e = 3;
const int num_v = 2;

typedef struct Edge {
    int start;
    int end;
} Edge;

typedef struct {
    int deg;
    int nome;
    Edge *edges;
} Vertex;
__host__ __device__ void print_data(Vertex *vert, int num_vertex, int num_edge){
  // print data
  for (int v = 0; v < num_vertex; v++)
    for (int e = 0; e < num_edge; e++)
      printf("vertex: %d, deg: %d, nome: %d, edge: %d, start: %d, end: %d\n", v, vert[v].deg, vert[v].nome, e, vert[v].edges[e].start, vert[v].edges[e].end);
}
__global__ void k(Vertex *vert, int num_vertex, int num_edge){
  print_data(vert, num_vertex, num_edge);
  // modify data
  vert[0].edges[1].end = 256;
}

int main(){
  // set up host data
  Edge he[num_v][num_e] = {{{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}}, {{5,6}, {6,7}, {7,8}}};
  Vertex hv[num_v];
  hv[0].deg = 32;
  hv[0].nome = 33;
  hv[0].edges = he[0];
  hv[1].deg = 34;
  hv[1].nome = 35;
  hv[1].edges = he[1];
  // set up device data
  Vertex* d_initial_partition;
  // allocate top level pointer to vertex array
  cudaMalloc((void **)&d_initial_partition, num_v * sizeof(Vertex));
  // copy top level array data
  cudaMemcpy(d_initial_partition, hv, num_v*sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  Edge *d_e[num_v]; // array of nested pointers for allocation on device
  // deep copy
  for (int i = 0; i < num_v; i++) {
    cudaMalloc(d_e+i, num_e*sizeof(Edge)); // allocate nested pointer
    cudaMemcpy(d_e[i], he[i], num_e*sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // copy data to nested pointer
    cudaMemcpy(&((d_initial_partition+i)->edges), d_e+i, sizeof(Edge *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);}//copy nested pointer value to proper location in top level array
  k<<<1,1>>>(d_initial_partition, num_v, num_e);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  // copy data back
  // deep copy
  for (int i = 0; i < num_v; i++)
    cudaMemcpy(he[i], d_e[i], num_e*sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(hv, d_initial_partition, num_v*sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // fix up pointers
  hv[0].edges = he[0];
  hv[1].edges = he[1];
  print_data(hv, num_v, num_e);
}

# nvcc -o t149 t149.cu
# compute-sanitizer ./t149
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 0, start: 1, end: 2
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 1, start: 2, end: 3
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 2, start: 3, end: 4
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 0, start: 5, end: 6
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 1, start: 6, end: 7
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 2, start: 7, end: 8
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 0, start: 1, end: 2
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 1, start: 2, end: 256
vertex: 0, deg: 32, nome: 33, edge: 2, start: 3, end: 4
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 0, start: 5, end: 6
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 1, start: 6, end: 7
vertex: 1, deg: 34, nome: 35, edge: 2, start: 7, end: 8
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
#
```

copying the device data back to the host is done using all the same methods and pointers and reverse sequence used to copy from host to device.

Comment: Ok so then I have a correct `d_initial_partition` now to copy it back to the host, I should do the `cudaMemcpy from Device to host` of each `Edge` and then do the general copy of the array?
What I'm doing now is a `for loop` where for each iteration I allocate space for the i-th edge on the host variable and then `cudaMemcpy` of `d_initial_partition[i].edge to the host[i].edge` and at the end of the loop I do a general `cudaMemcpy of d_initial_partition to host`...? 
``

Comment: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/function-doesnt-copy-all-the-elements-i-want/285427

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to

1. Allocate the array of `Vertex` on the device.
2. Allocate the arrays of `Edge` for the `edges` members on the device.
3. Set the pointers to the arrays of `Edge` to each `edges` members. Note that the `edges` members are on the device.

```
Vertex* d_initial_partition;
// 1
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex));
// copy deg and nome
cudaMemcpy(d_initial_partition, initial_partition, numNodes * sizeof(Vertex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
    Edge* edges;
    // 2
    cudaMalloc((void **)&edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge));
    // copy edges
    if(initial_partition[0].deg != 0){
        cudaMemcpy(edges, initial_partition[i].edges, initial_partition[i].deg * sizeof(Edge), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }
    // 3
    cudaMemcpy(&d_initial_partition[i].edges, &edges, sizeof(Edge*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do the same if I want to copy then this variable to a host variable?
I would like to check if effectively the edges field has been filled correctly

Comment: Btw, I tried it and then I tried first to copy only `d_initial_partition[0].name` on the host and is all ok, then I tried to copy on the host the value `d_initial_partition[0].edges[0].end`, but still goes in segmentation fault...